# Azure or Amazon for hosting Demos?

Tags: azure

For a team I am considering either hosting VMs with Azure or Amazon. These could be quite some different configurations and installs and probably dozens of images. I also have to look at the costs.

From my logical reasoning it seems Amazon is more handier BUT i am not sure. This is my reasoning:

A) on Azure you pay for instances even if they are stopped.
   a. unless you have powershell 3 / azure extensions installed, download the instances as   vm, then kill the instance. This means that also a non technical user giving a demo will have to go through this and have powershell azure installed on his laptop. I dont know if this is "handy".

B) on Amazon he/she simply clicks "stop"

---

- Note that storage costs will probably be around 1 dollar per 10 Gib if you leave them as storage on both platforms. So with considerable amount of images you probably will have to take them local anyway if you want to prevent the 1 dollar per 10 Gib. But also here Im looking for advise as many of you will probably have already set something up like this to prevent also the storage costs? (because in this case also a shared storage medium is needed so if person 1 uses it , changes some things, then downloads it to the shared storage, then person 2 can use it with the changes of person 1).
- on Azure we can reserve a DNS name so that is handy, on Amazon we have to give the elastic IP free and get a new IP the next time (unless we dont give the elastic ip address free which means costs for the ip address since it is not in use).

**update** : Im looking into SkyTap and CloudShare (Cloudshare is about $50 a month for a developer unlimited usage),  SkyTap is $250 a month for 5 users (200GB Storage)) so CloudShare seems to be more obvious for 1 developer cant judge for a team yet.

Comment: Have you considered CloudShare for demos? (I'm not affiliated).

Comment: @james-love not yet .... but adding it :)

Comment: @james-love i think CloudShare is perfect... thanks

Comment: @james-love but I also ran against SkyTap - also seems interesting

Comment: MS has announced changes to Azure pricing.  you will no longer charged for stopped instances - if you have an MSDN subscription you get a "monthly per diem" for use of Azure services, the amount depends on the subscription type ($50,$100, and $150). Additonally MSDN subscibers get a discount rate on Azuer of anywhere from 20% to 90% off, depending on the service used.  This was announced at TechEd a couple of weeks ago.  Scott Guthrie has a blog with the changes http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/03/windows-azure-announcing-major-improvements-for-dev-test-in-the-cloud.aspx

Comment: Personally, I felt AWS is good and easy to understand.

Comment: This question is fairly opinion based. Could we add some of these comments as an answer and designate this a wiki? Otherwise I am going to vote close so that it doesn't show up in the unanswered questions list. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: uhm... well... its 1 year after i posted this question so a lot of new stuff has come up in the meanwhile. I feel however this is a question many developers have. It could be made very smart using metrics such as costs (detailed)